# Parsing JSON empty string value with Grails 2.4

Tags: json, grails

Creating a RESTlike API with Grails 2.4 i have to parse JSON content e.g. for UPDATE/PATCH verbs.

I expect that null and empty string values are parsed both to null but the behavior i see is that when i send a `"{'name':'p1', 'description':''}"`this is parsed as`[description:, name:p1]`that is not a null value since it's not able to handle a `paramsMap.getAt("description") != null` condition

Have you seen this behavior? ... is it possible to make the default marshaller to translate the value to a null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the documentation explain:

> Web requests resulting from form submissions will have blank strings, not null, for input fields that have no value. Keep this in mind when doing mass property binding to properties that are not nullable. The default behavior is such that a blank string will not validate for nullable: false since the data binder will convert blank strings to null. This includes empty strings and blank strings. A blank string is any string such that the trim() method returns an empty string. To turn off the conversion of empty strings to null set the grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull property to false in Config.groovy. See the data binding section for more details on data binding.

So the default behavior of the marshaller is to translate it to null.

Check if in configuration you have:

```
// the default value for this property is true
grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull = false
```

If yyes, it's the problem.

I have try to post some data with empty parameters and they result null.

However groovy have a lot of side effect, infact as you write if you do:

```
print params.description != null ? 'Not null' : 'Null'
```

You get 'Not null'

But if you write:

```
params.description ? 'Not null' : 'Null'
```

you get 'Null'

This are screenshot that i made in groovy shell

[image: First usage]

[image: Second usage]

So in the end don't use != null :D

Comment: Also i've realized about checking against JSONObject.NULL instead a plain null reserved word ... and the behavior seems to be also different. I see a bit of mess here ... but maybe it's me